# Ver relaciones entre tablas de MySQL

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Estoy haciendo pruebas con una base de datos que me han pasado, la cual tiene relaciones entre tablas, donde se guardan los `id` de una tabla en otra.

Necesito poder ver las relaciones que existen entre estas tablas, ya que es muy grande la base de datos y no consigo encontrar las relaciones.

He estado buscando información y no he encontrado nada, por lo que me gustaría saber si existe alguna manera para poder ver la relación que existe entre las tablas. No me importa si es en modo visual, donde se vea con flechas, o si existe algún tipo de consulta que me devuelva las relaciones.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: has ``describe tutabla`` en la consola de mysql

Comment: Muchas gracias @JavierG.Raya, pero no puedo ver desde que tabla se le llama a cada campo?

Comment: vale ahora te añado la respuesta para que se resuelva

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que usar `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` para revisar la metadata de la base de datos.

En este caso, hay que mirar así

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'nombre_esquema_de_tabla'
      AND REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = 'tu_tabla';
```

Eso va a pintar todos los references a columnas de esa tabla.

Comment: Muchas gracias, justo lo que estaba buscando. Un saludo

Answer (score 2):

intentaré ayudarte ya que aún no puedo usar los comentarios y tengo que usar las respuestas.

Tienes varias opciones, podrías examinar las constraints de la tabla en cuestión para saber que relaciones tiene con que tablas, un `select * from all_constraints` y te debería printear las relaciones de toda la base de datos en cuestión.

Luego tambien depende que SGBD estes utilizando puedes hacer un diagrama Entidad/Relacion de base de datos para poder verlo de manera visual, te dejo un tutorial bastante sencillo usando SGDB Mysql workbench, espero haberte ayudado. https://www.javierrguez.com/generar-diagrama-entidad-relacion-mysql/

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte Alejandro. Un par de cosas a detallar: El select que me has puesto no me funciona, me dice que no existe la tabla `all_constraints` en mi base de datos. Por otro lado, he probado a crear el diagrama ER, siguiendo el enlace que me has proporiconado, pero no me enseña ninguna relación entre las tablas, lo que me hacer pensar que cuando crearon esta base de datos no crearon ninguna relación, ya que, ¿Cuando creo este modelo, me enseña también las relaciones con flechas como en los ejemplos que aparecen? Un saludo

Comment: Deberían aparecerte en efecto las flechas indicando las relaciones existentes entre las tablas, en cuanto a la tabla `all_constraints` prueba con lo siguiente,  `select * from user_constraints where table_name = 'nombre de la tabla' ` a ver si de esta manera puedes ir sacando las relaciones de tabla en tabla. Y por ultimo haciendo referencia al tema de que cuando se creó no insertaron las relaciones no creo que afecte, ya que cuando quieres hacer una relación nueva después de crear el modelo haces un `ALTER TABLE` y debería detectarlo, siento no poder ser de más ayuda y mucha suerte!

Comment: Gracias Alejandro, pero me temo de que no me ha servido lo que me has dicho,h eprobado la consulta que me has puesto, pero me dice que la tabla user_constraints no existe. He utilizado todos los comandos de `all_constraints` que aparecen [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024981/list-of-constraints-from-mysql-database](Aquí), pero me devuelve tablas vacías, por lo que supongo que con esto y con el model ER tengo suficiente para darme cuenta de que no hay relaciones, por lo que tendré que buscar a mano los campos. Muchas gracias de todos modos, buen finde

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Si deseas ver los datos que tienes con sus relaciones, existe un comando de MySQL llamado `DESCRIBE`. El comando ya es muy descriptivo: lo que hace es describir el contenido de tu seleccionada tabla.

```
DESCRIBE tutabla
```

**Por ejemplo:** La tabla *articulos*.

```
DESCRIBE articulos
```

**La salida de eso es:**

| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| cod_art | varchar(6) | NO | PRI |  |  |
| descripcion | varchar(45) | YES |  |  |  |
| precio | float | YES |  |  |  |
| stock | int(11) | YES |  |  |  |
| caducidad | tinyint(1) | YES |  |  |  |
| cod_prov | varchar(4) | YES |  |  |  |
| observaciones | varchar(45) | YES |  |  |  |

[<kbd>Ejecutar Ejemplo</kbd>](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/274)

**Puedes también optar por:**

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE articulos ;
```

[<kbd>Ejecutar Ejemplo</kbd>](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/277)

Comment: Muchas gracias Javier, pero me gustaría saber si hay alguna manera de que me enseñe también en que otra tabla se utiliza la clave. Por ejemplo: Imaginemos que tengo una tabla usuarios, y otra tabla de oficinas. En la tabla oficinas, hay un campo que se guardará el id del usuario que está en cada oficina. Podría ver en este caso que el campo `ID` de los usuarios se utilizan en la tabla oficinas? Gracias

Comment: @Maidagan lo acabo de modificar

Comment: Ahora lo miro, que estoy al telefono

Comment: avisa si funciona @Maidagan

Comment: He probado lo que me has propuesto para ver como se ha creado la tabla, pero me dice como se ha creado la tabla de `usuarios` en este caso, y no me dice si en la `oficina` está este campo. Lo que me estoy planteando, es que cuando se hizo esta base de datos, no se creó ninguna relación entre las tablas, ya que he probado lo que me ha propuesto Alejandro del modelo ER, y tampoco me las enseña, seguiré buscando información. Gracias de todos modos

Comment: vale amigo ::))